# Can the same number be used for two different types of SMS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Is it possible to use the same number for two different types of SMS in MobileConnect?

For instance, I'd like to have an outbound message and a text response message, both with the same number. Can this be done or do I need to get a different number for each message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the same Shord/Long code? The answer is **YES**, it can be done using one Short/Long code only..

> Use a short code to ***send and receive SMS messages*** within the United
>   States; use a short or long code in other countries.

**Reference:**

[Keywords and Codes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_managing_keywords_on_short_and_long_codes_in_your_mobileconnect_accounts.htm&type=5)

Comment: Ok. So let's say an outbound message gets sent to a customer. The customer replies to that message with a keyword, and the text response message gets triggered and sent to the customer. Is that how it would work?

Comment: Exactly, that's the Next Keyword functionality. Check out the help here for more details: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_use_next_keyword.htm&type=5